# Add toolbar button and menu item in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying my hand at developing Firefox addons. I have developed the basic javascript code for the extension. Now I want a menu item in the Tools Menu and a toolbar button. I can't get these two elements to appear, however(The button should appear in the Customize menu, IMO, and the menu item in the Tools Menu). What am I doing wrong?

Here is the chrome.manifest file:

```
content     droptunesshuffle    chrome/content/
content     droptunesshuffle    chrome/content/ contentaccessible=yes
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://droptunesshuffle/content/browser.xul

locale  droptunesshuffle    en-US   locale/en-US/

skin    droptunesshuffle    classic/1.0 skin/
style   chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://droptunesshuffle/skin/skin.css
```

Here is the browser.xul overlay file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://droptunesshuffle/skin/skin.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://droptunesshuffle/locale/en-US/translations.dtd">
<overlay id="sample" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

        <script type="application/x-javascript src="chrome://droptunesshuffle/content/shuffle.js" />

        <menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup">

            <menuitem label="Droptunes Shuffle "key="link-target-finder-run-key" oncommand="droptunesshuffle.run()"/>
        </menupopup>


        <keyset>
            <key id="droptunes-shuffle-run-key" modifiers="shift" key="S" oncommand="droptunesshuffle.run()"/>
        </keyset>

        <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
            <toolbarbutton id="droptunes-shuffle-toolbar-button" class=”toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional” image="chrome://droptunesshuffle/skin/icon.png" label="Droptunes Shuffle" tooltiptext="&droptunesshuffle;" oncommand="droptunesshuffle.run()"/>
        </toolbarpalette>
</overlay>
```

The skin.css file:

```
#droptunes-shuffle-toolbar-button{
list-style-image: url("chrome://droptunesshuffle/skin/icon.png");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is a bootstrap addon. Run the code and it will add a context menu to all windows.

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/8776519

Now just change adding context menu to add to the menu item context that already exists.
In my gist here, change the context menu id to 'menu_ToolsPopup' this will add the menu item to the tools menu.

To add a toolbar button do the same thing to create a menuitem but now create a 'toolbarbutton' element and append it to id 'nav-bar'.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. Can you tell me though, why is my code not working?

Comment: Im not sure, I don't work with overlays too much. I only recently started working with chrome.manifest as well